# How to update multiple column values in MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I want to update image path in MySQL table. Table schema is this:

> table_brands - brand_id, brand_name, brand_image_path

Currently path is stored as-

```
`images/1.png`
`images/2.png`
```

I want to make it as

```
 `images/brands/1.png`
 `images/brands/2.png`
```

Also for some entries path is stored as

```
 `images/brands/1.png`
 `images/brands/2.png`
```

so changes should not be done for such entries.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use replace function for this purpose only for the image paths that don't contain 'brand'

```
 UPDATE table_brand
 SET brand_image_path = REPLACE(brand_image_path, 'images', 'images/brands')
 WHERE brand_image_path NOT LIKE '%brands%';
```